# Catching error : 'QhullError' is not defined

Tags: python, exception

I have troubles handling an exception in my python code. The error occurs when trying to to 3D interpolation on a certain grid, using the 'linear' method ; this yields a QhullError. 
The interpolation works fine using 'nearest'. 
Therefore I want to catch 'QhullError' using 'try/except'.

When I run the code I get

> NameError: name 'QhullError' is not defined

I also tried a custom class to handle the exception, but that doesn't catch anything at all...

Any idea on what I'm missing here ?

Thanks a lot !

Find the code below :

```
import numpy as np
import warnings
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator as Lin3DInterp
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator as Near3DInterp
from random import random


# %% Here I tried a custom class to handle my exception... didn't work either

# class QhullError(Exception):
#     pass

# %%

# choosing interpolation method : 'linear' or 'nearest'
InterpMethod = 'linear'

# evenly spaced grid
grid_points = np.squeeze(np.array([[np.linspace(0, 9, 10)],
                                   [np.linspace(0, 9, 10)],
                                   [np.linspace(0, 9, 10)]]).transpose())
# some random values
grid_points_values = random()*grid_points


if InterpMethod == 'nearest':
    # this works fine
    interp_func = Near3DInterp(grid_points, grid_points_values)

elif InterpMethod == 'linear':

    try:
        # QhullError here, trying to catch that
        interp_func = Lin3DInterp(grid_points, grid_points_values)

    except QhullError:
        warnings.warn('QhullError : linear interpolation failed, '
                      'using ''nearest'' method instead')
        interp_func = Near3DInterp(grid_points, grid_points_values)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to import it from here:

```
from scipy.spatial.qhull import QhullError
```